# How to change remoteurl of jquery struts2 dialog(remote)?

Tags: struts2, struts

I am using struts2-jquery plugin & using dialog(remote) so i have specified remoteurl before dialog code as shown below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="myremoteaction"/>
    <sj:dialog id="mydialog3" href="%{remoteurl}" title="Remote Dialog open on Click" autoOpen="false"/>
   <sj:a openDialog="mydialog3">Open Dialog</sj:a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i click on hyperlink instead of opening dialog directly first i want to change its remoteurl & then want to open it
Can somebody tell me how should i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I've not tested it but i believe it will give you a clue on how to solve the problem. Change the value of the `href` attribute before opening the dialog using something like this:

```
$("#mydialog3").dialog( "option" , "href", your_new_url );
$("#mydialog3").dialog('open')
```

You can also visit the [Struts2 jquery showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) page for more clarification.